# javascript not refreshing tabs in internet explorer

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console

I have an embedded VF page in the salesforce console and am trying to get the page to refresh when a user clicks a button. I have the functionality working in chrome, firefox, etc, but not in IE. Here is the VF component:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!updateStatus}" onComplete="loadNext('{!myobj.id}');return false;">
```

and here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var rName, rId, curTabId;
        function loadNext(recapId) {
            rName = recapName;
            rId = recapId;
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(findCurTabID);
        }


        var findCurTabID = function findCurTabID(result) {
            if (result.success == true) {
                curTabId = result.id;
                if(!rName) {
                        window.alert("There are no more un-closed records.");
                        sforce.console.closeTab(curTabId);
                } else sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(curTabId, rId , true, rName, refreshSuccess); 
            } 
        };

        var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) {
            //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
            if (result.success == true) {
                console.log('Primary tab refreshed successfully');
            } else {
                console.log('Primary did not refresh');
            }
        };
    </script>
```

What is the solution to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this wasn't working is because IE doesn't recognize the console commands unless the console is open. So i removed the console commands and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I found this workaround

```
<div id="ieBrowserFix" style="display:none;">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="IE" subtitle="BrowserFix" />
</div>
```

It seems that some javascript fails in IE without the sectionHeader component.

Comment: so i just need to wrap the button in the div?

Comment: No I've just added the section header on the top of the visualforce page.

Comment: @TylerHarrington have you resolved the issue?